# How to access multiple layers of ManyToManyField in template?

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many

I have a three 'layers' deep model, that i's like to access through my template:

Models:

```
class Match(models.Model):

    pl1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pl2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(Scoreboard)
    active = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    turn = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Match " + str(self.id)
```

---

```
class Scoreboard(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

---

I'm just guessing, but to get the names of the users connected to each 'Match', shouldn't it be something like this:

```
{% for active in matches %}
{{active}} - {{active.boards.user}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boards` is the ManyToMany, so there are *many* scoreboards to each `match`. So, you need to iterate through them.

```
{% for active in matches %}
  {{ active }}:
  {% for board in active.boards.all %}
      {{ board.user }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```